# Draw a triangle out of asterisks using for loops

Tags: python, geometry, python-idle

```
size = int(input("Enter an odd number width: "))
    for row in range(1, (size+1)/2, 1):
        for character in range(1, size):

            print("*"*character)
```

Why does it keep telling me "float object cannot be interpreted as an integer"? I know its because of the (size+1)/2 but I don't think it should make a difference?

Its supposed to create a triangle that looks like this:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
*************
```

(rows are the width+1/2, and the entered number is the largest row of asterisks, also the rows increase by increments of 2 each time (i.e. 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13).

Comment: Are you using Python 3? In that case, division of two integer will give you a float. Use `(size + 1)//2` to get an integer

Comment: You need only 1 loop: `for i in range(nRows): print '*'*(i*2 + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `(size+1)/2` *could* theoretically have a fractional part, Python always returns a floating point number from it. `range` doesn't accept floats because there is no *general* way to turn it into an integer without potentially losing information. Neither of these steps special-cases the particular inputs that don't trigger these problems.

You don't care about those things, because you consider `size` being even to be an invalid input. But Python doesn't know you don't care about the potential data loss unless you tell it - which you can do like this:

```
(size + 1) // 2
```

This removes the fractional part of the number, and only gives you the integer part (ie, rounded toward minus infinity).

Comment: It's not round-to-zero; `//` floors the result.

Comment: @user2357112 so it does. I've changed my post to say "toward minus infinity", although, of course, they are equivalent *in this specific situation* since the OP's code expects positive numbers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

because float object cannot be interpreted as integer. Use integer division:

```
(size + 1) // 2
```

Otherwise it will result on a float number (on Python 3)